box-shadow bleeding outside of clip-path bounds
I'm seeing anti-aliased vertical lines between items in a horizontal menu that shouldn't be there to the best of my knowledge.

I'm trying to create seamless shadows below all of items that aren't active, using a combination of box-shadow and clip-path to remove the shadow on all sides but the bottom, but it appears some of the shadow is escaping the clip-path.
The lines are more or less visible at different zoom levels, leading me to think that the element bounds used by the box shadow and clip paths aren't the same (different by half pixels perhaps?) but I've not been able to validate that by specifying fixed widths - what am I doing wrong here? Any help much appreciated!


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  --color-text: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  --color-theme-1: #00a99d;
  --shadow-bottom: 0 -4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  --shadow-side: 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  --shadow-clip: border-box inset(0 0 -4px 0);
}
nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 60, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 3em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  list-style: none;
}
li,
.spacer {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-bottom);
  clip-path: var(--shadow-clip);
}
li[aria-current='page'] {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: none;
  clip-path: var(--shadow-clip);
}
li[aria-current='page'] a {
  color: var(--color-text-light);
}

li[aria-current='page']::before,
li[aria-current='page']::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-side);
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 1px;
}
li[aria-current='page']::before {
  left: -3px;
}
li[aria-current='page']::after {
  right: -3px;
}
nav a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  color: var(--color-text);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="spacer"> </div>
        <ul>
            <li aria-current='page'}>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/sverdle">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="spacer"> </div>
    </nav>
</header>




I see no vertical lines when I zoom in or out in your snippet

It looks fine on myside too without any line.

I'm seeing lines at 140% zoom in Chromium-based browsers on Windows 10, does not appear to repro in Firefox though. Browser specific bug?

firstly made your box border size and then gave it box-shadow

I added box-sizing: border-box to everything but it didn't seem to help - could you clarify?

This does not seem to answer the question, how does this fix the issue? Please include the code snippet provided in the question with your provided solution
